# macOS: Finder constantly restores "Desktop" favorite under Sidebar

Tags: finder, macos

Finder acts weirdly, or I'm unaware of some design or something (like "Enter do not open files by default" thing).

In Finder:

- go to Finder Preferences
- navigate to "sidebar" tab
- uncheck [] Desktop
- re-login to macOS and Desktop favorite sill there

Maybe someone can shed a light on this one.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [First Aid](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22243?locale=en_US)? If there are problems, you may want to [use the Disk Utility Tool from Recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). If you reboot and hold down <kbd>command⌘</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> you will boot into your local repair disk, or if you hold down <kbd>command⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> you will boot into the internet recovery mode (you will, of course, need internet access and will want to give it a while to load all the options up.)

Also, try [zapping the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) by holding down <kbd>command⌘</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> when rebooting?

You may also simply need to [trash your sidebar preference files](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/finder.html):
`/Users/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`
...or even the Finder preference file:
`/Users/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

Also check `/Library/Preferences/` and `/System/Library/Preferences/` to see if there are duplicates.

Note: If you are not the owner of the computer, speak to the owner/admin before trying any of this and request permission from your system administrator. If you are the owner you may need to assign this login account admin status.

Comment: I tried wiping out of Finder configs under my ~/Library directory.  Basically I moved on.  Linked all of my media directories to external drive and it's not displaying while external driver is not connected to my mac.  But that is my way of solving, since I don't have enough space on my 121G SSD.